# Weak-star spanning system in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, weak-topology

Recently, I have learned the following surprising result of Hedenhalm and Montes-Rodriguez(2011, Ann. Math. Theorem 3.1): As $n$ ranges over the integers, the functions $e^{\pi inx}$ and  $e^{\pi i\beta n/x}$ form a weak-star- spanning system in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $0<\beta\leq1$. The proof is not long but quite technical when first reading.

I'm curious about what will hapen when condiering the span of their multiplication and division, thus I have the following 'much weaker' question: Does
$$
\text{span}\{ e^{\pi itx}, t\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$
form a weak-star system in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$?
Furthermore, does
$$
\text{span}\{ e^{\pi it(x+\frac{1}{x})}, e^{\pi it(x-\frac{\beta}{x})}, t\in\mathbb{R}\}? 
$$
form a weak-star system in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ for any but fixed $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$?

Two different point here:  $e^{\pi it(x+\frac{1}{x})}$ is no longer periodic and $t$ ranges onver $\mathbb{R}$, so I think the situation is quite different, and I guess that the threshold might be whether or not $\beta=\pm 1$.